# How can I capture successes/failures/non-attempts with InsertBatch using the MongoDB C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The `InsertBatch` method returns an `IEnumerable<WriteConcernResult>`, which I would assume would return an `IEnumerable` list of results with one result per document passed to `InsertBatch`.

This is not the case.  When it is successful, it returns a single `WriteConcernResult`, even if I pass 100 documents to the `InsertBatch` method.  When there is an error, the method throws an exception and I can't tell which records were inserted, which insert(s) failed, and which documents were not attempted.

Is there a way I can capture this information?

**Example with two successful inserts**

```
var myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
myObjects.Add(new MyObject{Id = 1234});
myObjects.Add(new MyObject{Id = 2345});

var results = myCollection.InsertBatch(myObjects, WriteConcern.Acknowledged);

// This only returns a single object, not two
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OK?: {0}", result.Ok);
}
```

**Example with 2 successful inserts, 1 failure, 1 unattempted**

```
var myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
myObjects.Add(new MyObject{Id = 3456});    // succeeds
myObjects.Add(new MyObject{Id = 4567});    // succeeds
myObjects.Add(new MyObject{Id = 4567});    // fails
myObjects.Add(new MyObject{Id = 5678});    // unattempted

// This throws a MongoDuplicateKeyException
var results = myCollection.InsertBatch(myObjects, WriteConcern.Acknowledged);
```

Is it possible to have the MongoDB C# Driver attempt all inserts and then just report the failures?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re doing a bulk insert and do get an error, your program will need to handle the possibility of a partial bulk insert. If your particular use case doesn't care about missing a few inserts, you can
add the continue_on_error=True argument to insert, in which case the insert will insert
as many documents as possible, and report an error on the last insert that failed. (some part of 'Mongodb Applied Design Patterns' book')

```
var options = new MongoInsertOptions();
options.Flags = InsertFlags.ContinueOnError;

try
{
    myCollection.InsertBatch(myObjects, options);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                                
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the full list of errors instead of just the last error (if there are multiple errors)?  It seems like that's what was meant to be returned by the InsertBatch call.

Comment: I believe its not. MongoDb throws (returns) only last exception according to mongo documents and I think its reasonable. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/